# Scala Play Public Asset Fingerprinting Version

Tags: scala, playframework, fingerprint

I've successfully setup scala (play framework) fingerprinting on our public assets by doing the following:

plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")
```

build.sbt

`pipelineStages := Seq(digest, gzip) // added digest`

routes

```
Setup relevant route for public /*files
```

This will produce something like the following in the page source:

/stylesheets/730252eec90cb8dab9c4a8a5ee7277ac-styles.min.css"

My question is how will this MD5 hash change in the future. Does it depend on the 'Version' in the build.sbt? Or will it automatically update each time you redeploy?

```
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT" // Do I need to change this each time i redeploy?
```

Comment: I think that the hash is generated using the original file contents, so that hash will change only when the source file changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `sbt-digest` plugin has a lot of very clever change-detection stuff built in, if we look at the [source for sbt-digest](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-digest/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/digest/SbtDigest.scala), we can see that it actually relies on an [Ivy helper class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.ivy/ivy/2.0.0/org/apache/ivy/util/ChecksumHelper.java) to perform the digest calculation, and that helper only uses the **content of each `File`** to calculate the digest.

What this means is that as long as the content of a given asset remains the same (and also your digest algorithm e.g. `md5`), you can move it around on your filesystem and/or the URI path and it'll still have the same "filename" - a nice property.

So if you decide to introduce a new `main` subdirectory in `stylesheets`, your HTML goes from:

```
/stylesheets/730252eec90cb8dab9c4a8a5ee7277ac-styles.min.css
```

to

```
/stylesheets/main/730252eec90cb8dab9c4a8a5ee7277ac-styles.min.css
```

Comment: Great thanks for your answer. So to clarify, if styles.min.css has different content in the next deploy (eg I've added new css to the file), then the MD5 hash will automatically change?

Comment: Yep. I suppose it's technically possible for the new file to actually hash to the _same value_ as the old one, but I think we can rule that out for practical purposes ;-)